# Strictly positive compact operator commuting with a given Fredholm operator

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators, k-theory, unbounded-operators

In the following snippet from a paper by Jody Trout on the converse functional calculus, they mention the existence of a strictly positive compact operator $T$ commuting with a given self-adjoint, odd Fredholm operator on the standard graded Hilbert $A$-module. Could someone justify why such an operator always exists?

[image]